# How put cursor (android) to array 2 dimension?

Tags: java, android, arrays, cursor

I have this :

```
String [][] population = new String[indexOfChromosomes][indexOfGens];

for(int chromosomesNumber = 0; chromosomesNumber <= indexOfChromosomes ; chromosomesNumber++){
  for(int gensNumber = 0; gensNumber <= indexOfGens ; gensNumber++){
    Cursor r = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, key_foodstuff, key_calorie, key_carbohydrate, key_fat, 
      key_protein FROM (food INNER JOIN categories ON food.key_nocategory = 
      categories.nocategories) WHERE key_type='primary' 
      AND _id!=164 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", null);       

      if(r.moveToFirst()){              
       population[indexOfChromosomes][indexOfGens] = r.getString(0);
      }
   }
}
```

I got error when I run for this code :
 population[indexOfChromosomes][indexOfGens] = r.getString(0);

I wanna ask, how I put that cursor r on array 2 dimension ? Thx

Comment: What error are you getting? It's tough to tell what exactly you're trying to do here.

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: What does the logcat say? What's the full error message?

Comment: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
Fatal Exception : main
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: the last array item you can put into population can be population[indexOfChromosomes-1][indexOfGens-1].

Answer (score 1):

it looks like error is here :

```
String [][] population = new String[indexOfChromosomes][indexOfGens];

for(int chromosomesNumber = 0; chromosomesNumber <= indexOfChromosomes ; chromosomesNumber++){
    for(int gensNumber = 0; gensNumber <= indexOfGens ; gensNumber++){
```

size of array is `indexOfChromosomes` x `indexOfGens`, so it's indexes are `0..indexOfChromosomes-1`, and `0..indexOfGens-1`, while you are trying to access index `indexOfChromosomes` and `indexOfGens`.

It should be

```
for(int chromosomesNumber = 0; chromosomesNumber < indexOfChromosomes ; chromosomesNumber++){
    for(int gensNumber = 0; gensNumber < indexOfGens ; gensNumber++){
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on how you've written your code, it looks like inside your for loop

```
 population[indexOfChromosomes][indexOfGens]
```

should be

```
population[chromosomesNumber][gensNumber]
```

Comment: I have already changed it, for the first looping of chromosomesNumber, it successed, but for the second looping it has error, same row of code got error and the error is same too : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ... Thx

Answer (score 0):

Your approach confuses me. I don't know a lot about SQL, but it looks like you're repeatedly querying your database for a single row at random. I've read that this is a costly operation. I think you're better off  getting the full data set once, at the beginning, and iterating over that.

How do indexOfChromosomes and indexOfGens relate to the database with columns "foodstuff" etc? I'm not seeing a connection...

This is modified from my own method that works well in Android. If the rawQuery works, then the whole lot should:

```
// The order of this array will affect final array
// I would also use this array in the query itself
String[] columnNames = {
        "_id", "key_foodstuff", "key_calorie", "key_carbohydrate", "key_fat", "key_protein"
};
Cursor r = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, key_foodstuff, key_calorie,
        key_carbohydrate, key_fat, key_protein FROM (food INNER JOIN
        categories ON food.key_nocategory = categories.nocategories)
        WHERE key_type='primary' AND _id!=164", null);

int rowCount = r.getCount();
int columnCount = columnNames.length;
// create the required array with appropriate dimensions
String[][] array = new String[rowCount][columnCount];
// begin iterating over the cursor
if (r.moveToFirst()) {
    int row = 0;
    do {
        // for each row of the cursor, get the values from all
        // of the columns
        for (int column = 0; column < columnCount; column++) {
            array[row][column] = cursor.getString(cursor.
                    getColumnIndex(columnNames[column]));
        }
        row++;
    } while (r.moveToNext());
}
```